# Unable to install drush on mac 10.9.2

Tags: 7, drush

Lately I was trying to install drush for the first time. This is what I did..

- Installed the drush tool manually
- Extracted and renamed the tool to `/Library/Drush`
- Gave the `/Library/Drush/drush` tool execution permissions.
- Created an alias for drush in `~/.bashrc`
- Tried to bash drush by entering the alias `drush`, that's when I got the first problem:
  `Unable to load autoload.php. Drush now requires Composer in order to install its dependencies and autoload classes. Please see README.md`
- After lots of searching I tried way to many things:

  - `which drush` doesn't return anything.
  - Installing the composer (at `/usr/local/bin/composer`) results in this `The requested package drush/drush 1.0.0 could not be found` problem when executing `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`

Help would be appreciated, because I don't know what I could do to make it work.

Thank you in advance, `F.

Comment: If you're struggling to do it manually, why not just use Homebrew? `brew install drush` is all you need

Comment: @Clive This did the trick, thought I tried this already. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error while installing the drush on MAC, I have tried the following and that worked for me:

```
composer self-update
ln -s /path/to/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
```

I have downloaded the Drush from this git repository: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush

And followed the method described here for installing the Drush on MAC: https://www.drupal.org/node/1674222

---

For Installing Drush on Mac using Homebrew, check https://www.drupal.org/node/954766

Comment: This didn't work for me neither, still got the same error. But I didn't used the drush download you use (drush-master). The additional solution @Clive commented did work!

Comment: @Fleuv Yes for MAC using Homebrew is a good option, anyways I have also mentioned this as well as a alternate option :)